# Another way to compile java without servlet-api

Tags: java

Up to this point I used the Tomcat installation that comes with servlet-api.jar to compile my java files. Is there another way to compile it? Simply using the JDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: This answer supposes your project includes some servlets, or other Servlet-related components, which can be guessed from your question.

---

No, you can't compile your project using only the JDK. The reason for this is that classes defined in `servlet-api.jar` does NOT exist in the standard class library, and the compiler does NOT know their definition (what are their methods, attributes, and so on).

If you want to use Servlet-related classes, you need to include a working copy of `servlet-api.jar` in your project. This copy can come from Tomcat, as in your case, or from another Servlet-compliant application server, such as GlassFish, JBoss, Jetty, or one of the many other existing ones.